# Reload screen when the tab is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-maps

I have 2 tabs in my project- outer Tab and inner Tab. In my inner Tab I have maps and lists which shows markers and details.

Now I want to reload (fetch data) when i change the tab from either maps to lists or vice versa. I could only call them once ie first visit as i have been calling the API from component Will Mount(). 
How to recognise the tab movements and reload map?

Any lead would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I supposed you are using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation). They recently introduced navigation listener in their API (willBlur, willFocus, didBlur and didFocus events).

Then, an idea would be to use those listeners in your screen to refresh the data you need.

Example:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.didFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      () => { console.log('did focus') },
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.didFocusListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return ( /* your render */ );
  }
}
```

Documentation: [Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

Comment: Where should i be adding this listener in? as componentWillMount() is called once. does adding this listener in componentWillReceiveProps() work?

Comment: Add it to the `componentDidMount()` of the tab you are interested in and do not forget to remove it in the `componentWillUnmount()`. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the useEffect hook to handle the component render change.

```
useEffect(() => {
//core logic for component rerender
}, [dataChangelistener]);
```